# Coin Flip Simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I ask the user if they want to play and then start the simulation? And if they don't the program prints a goodbye message. And print the total number of times the coin was flipped at the end.

```
import random 
def num_of_input():
  userName = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print("Hello " + userName + "!" + " This program simulates flipping a coin.")
  while True:
    try:
     time_flip= int(input("How many times of flips do you want? "))
    except:
      print("Please try again.")
      continue
    else:
      break
  return time_flip    

def random_flip():
  return random.randint(0, 1)


def count_for_sides():
  count_head=0
  count_tail=0
  times=num_of_input()
  while True:
    if count_head + count_tail == times:
      break

    else:
      if random_flip()==0:
        count_head+=1
      else:
        count_tail+=1

  print()    
  print(str(count_head) + " came up Heads")
  print(str(count_tail) + " came up Tails")

count_for_sides()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input from the user before calling the `count_for_sides` method and call it if they opt in.

```
import random 
def num_of_input():
  userName = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print("Hello " + userName + "!" + " This program simulates flipping a coin.")
  while True:
    try:
     time_flip = int(input("How many times of flips do you want? "))
    except:
      print("Please try again.")
      continue
    else:
      break
  return time_flip    

def random_flip():
  return random.randint(0, 1)


def count_for_sides():
  count_head=0
  count_tail=0
  times=num_of_input()
  while True:
    if count_head + count_tail == times:
      break

    else:
      if random_flip()==0:
        count_head+=1
      else:
        count_tail+=1

  print()    
  print(str(count_head) + " came up Heads")
  print(str(count_tail) + " came up Tails")

userWantsToPlay = input("Do you want to play this game? (Y/n): ")
if (userWantsToPlay == 'Y'):
  count_for_sides()
```

Comment: I wanted to add it after the Print("Hello " + userName + "!" + " This program simulates flipping a coin.")

Comment: You could move the first two lines of the num_of_input function to just above the userWantsToPlay line.